# a complex sql query with outer join

Tags: php, mysql, sql

there are two tables 
a

```
------------------------------
id  |  Name
------------------------------
1   |  Alpha
-----------------------------
2   |  Beta
-----------------------------
3   |  Gamma
-----------------------------
4   |  Delta
-----------------------------
```

and another table b with foreign key of table a

b

```
-----------------------------
id  | a_id | Film
-----------------------------
 1  |   1  | Bladerunner
-----------------------------
 2  |   1  | Star Wars
-----------------------------
 3  |   3  | Superman
-----------------------------
 4  |   4  | Rollerball
-----------------------------
```

Write an SQL query using outer join to get all names from table “a” that don't have a film starting with “S”.

Query result should be:

```
Beta
--------
Delta
```

Comment: Looks a lot like a homework question to me. What have tried?

Comment: too easy and dublicate, answers like this exists on stackoverflow.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the difference between "INNER JOIN" and "OUTER JOIN"?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use correlated subquery with `not exists`

**[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=ca1fb2493f0b7a386acffc808f7d0813)**

```
   SELECT * 
FROM   tablea a 
       LEFT JOIN tableb b 
              ON a.id = b.a_id 
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 
                   FROM   tableb b1 
                   WHERE  b.a_id = b1.a_id 
                          AND film LIKE 'S%')
```

OR you can use below query to avoid subquery

```
    SELECT NAME, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN film LIKE 'S%' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) 
FROM   t1 a 
       LEFT JOIN t2 b 
              ON a.id = b.a_id 
GROUP  BY NAME 
HAVING Sum(CASE 
             WHEN film LIKE 'S%' THEN 1 
             ELSE 0 
           END) = 0
```

OUTPUT:

```
name
Delta
Beta
```

Comment: Can you do the same without using sub-query?

Comment: @MKGarwa, I've added it without subquery - you can check

Comment: @MKGarwa '%S%' should be 'S%'

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.NAME 
FROM   a 
       LEFT JOIN b 
              ON a.id = b.a_id 
WHERE  a.NAME NOT IN (SELECT a.NAME 
                      FROM   a 
                             LEFT JOIN b 
                                    ON a.id = b.a_id 
                      WHERE  b.film LIKE 's%') 
GROUP  BY a.NAME
```

**output**

---

Beta

Delta

according to the OPs question which he has not mentioned and just gave output part in his question... he wants all the name of the table a  where film name do not start with letter S from table b. the above query fullfilled the requirements of OPs completely and in most standard way.

OP just mentioned the join in the question but he do not mentioned that he want those id name also which do not exist in table b in a_id i.e the output part beta.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/22310459)

Comment: @SagarChauhan the query is working now, I have missed the output part he wants...

Comment: Please add more description regarding how this code works.

Comment: @SagarChauhan Okay, I have given good description of OPs question and answer which he do not mentioned and just gave output...

Answer (score -1):

use substring and join

```
  select a.name from t1 a left join 
 t2 b on a.id=b.a_id
 where a.id  not in ( select b.a_id  from t2 b
  where 
upper(substring(b.Film,1,1))   like '%S%' and b.a_id is not null
    )
```

output

```
name
Delta
Beta
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=3ef75bf410fcc678d246a3159a70e0c3)

Comment: Question specifically says  'using outer join' are you suggesting an outer join is not required?

Comment: @P.Salmon Left join is left outer join.